# Kotlin service application icon

Tags: android, kotlin, service, icons

i tried to write a service on_boot_completed and it is working well. However, I tried to hide the application from app list.
I tried

```
    val p = applicationContext.packageManager
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        componentName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    )
```

adding this in MainActivity.kt but my service does not work when I add this. I tried to remove launcher-main from manifest. All of them is resulting an issue like below.

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I declared it in my manifest. So my question is; how can I hide my app icon in app list?

Answer (score 1):

just remove `intent-filter` declaration, these lines should be removed

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

leave only your `Activity`s tag without any content

```
<activity
    android:name="..."
    ... rest of params
    android:lastparam=""/>
```

note `/>` closing tag on end

edit: ofc this will hide your `Activity`s icon in launcher, but app itself still be visible in all apps list e.g. in system Settings, obviously with possibility for force stopping or uninstalling

Comment: I tried to do this, however when I do, service cannot start. It does not show, but it cannot get on_boot_completed intent.

Comment: just because removing above lines? looks like some protection which I doubt can be bypassed, but also curious now, upvoting answer

Comment: @snachmsm I think since activity is never ran app is stuck in [never used](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) priority bucket  which prevents it from receiving broadcasts.

Comment: thank for link, this may be this case... (ps. to prev comment, can't edit now: upvoting question, not answer)

Comment: I will look for it today, thanks, btw I upvote because you tried to help me. I will write again.